# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', What's wrong?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on a flash card app using Swift and I'm having a terrible go at it. Today, I've been stuck on some pretty basic stuff like transitioning between views at the press of a button, but after getting many different errors and starting over on the project multiple times I'm once again stuck.

Everything was working until I decided to add a UITextField to one of my View's and now whenever I transition to that view it crashes. But if I delete the UIText field from the view and unconnect it, things work fine. I'm at a lost here at what I'm doing wrong but I think it's probably related to what I've been doing wrong all day with these views and segues.

Edit: Here is the complete error message

```
2020-12-01 12:42:41.206345-0800 final_proj690[3252:142523] [Storyboard] Unknown class HiraganaViewController in Interface Builder file.
2020-12-01 12:42:41.224722-0800 final_proj690[3252:142523] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fa939d12790> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Question.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041daf2 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041d793 -[NSException init] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff207a5fca -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 325
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f38cea -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24279f7d -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2040729c -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 228
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2427612f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2175
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f40b48 -[UIViewController loadView] + 668
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f40ee3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f4165d -[UIViewController view] + 27
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f5933f -[UIViewController _setPresentationController:] + 100
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f51260 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1409
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f54db3 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4942
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f55bf6 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 98
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f55f2c -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 519
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f55b54 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f55fe2 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 155
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff247f6e05 __74-[UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 133
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff247fc71a -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 276
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff247fc5d8 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f44523 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 540
    22  final_proj690                       0x0000000103d46e66 $s13final_proj69014ViewControllerC14HiraganaButtonyySo8UIButtonCFyycfU_ + 118
    23  final_proj690                       0x0000000103d46f10 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 48
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103fda9c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103fdd316 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 557
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103ff0e8b _dispatch_source_invoke + 2205
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103fe8ca4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 687
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038bdab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038662e __CFRunLoopRun + 2685
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203856c6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2b76adb3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24675187 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2467a038 UIApplicationMain + 101
    34  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff541545f2 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
    35  final_proj690                       0x0000000103d4a8fa $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
    36  final_proj690                       0x0000000103d4a86e $s13final_proj69011AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
    37  final_proj690                       0x0000000103d4a949 main + 41
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20256409 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fa939d12790> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Question.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.0.2 - Device: iPhone 12 (4D085E44-F6B4-4CFC-B984-C54CA04EB2AE) - Runtime: iOS 14.2 (18B79) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
```

Here's my code:

Code for Main ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // create class variable that's accessible outside of viewToLoad()
    var centerY: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var top: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    var centerConstraintActive: Bool = true
    

    @IBAction func HiraganaButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let coloredView = ColoredView(width: 250, height: 50, color: .red)
        
        let lb = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: coloredView.frame.height/2, y: coloredView.frame.width/2, width: 50, height: 50))
        
        lb.font = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 30)
        lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lb.text="  Hiragana Time!"
        
        view.addSubview(coloredView)
        coloredView.addSubview(lb)
        lb.center = coloredView.center
        
        coloredView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        centerY = coloredView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        centerY?.isActive = true
        
        top = coloredView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HiraganaSegue", sender: self)
        }
 }
    
    @IBAction func KatakanaButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let coloredView = ColoredView(width: 250, height: 50, color: .systemTeal)
        
        let lb = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: coloredView.frame.height/2, y: coloredView.frame.width/2, width: 50, height: 50))
        
        lb.font = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 30)
        lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lb.text=" Katakana Time!"
        
        view.addSubview(coloredView)
        coloredView.addSubview(lb)
        lb.center = coloredView.center
        
        coloredView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        centerY = coloredView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        centerY?.isActive = true
        
        top = coloredView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "KatakanaSegue", sender: self)
        }    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @objc func coloredViewTapped() {
        toggle()
    }
    
    func toggle() {
            centerY?.isActive = false
            top?.isActive = true
    }


}
```

And here's the code for the view that crashes the app when it's transitioned too:

```
import UIKit

class HiraganaViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var Question: UIView!
    
    var flashCards = ["a" : "あ",
                      "i" : "い",
                      "u" : "う"
    ]
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

And here's the code for ColoredView class:

```
import UIKit

class ColoredView: UIView {
    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        // create the constraints (layout anchors)
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        
        // Turn off automatic "frame" constraints
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        backgroundColor = color
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Again I have a feeling it has something to do with my connections but when I check the connections list all I see is the stuff I linked... Any thoughts? Thanks :)

Comment: Please update your question with the complete error message.  It should tell you the name of the key that it can't match.

Comment: Thank you, I updated it with the full code. Sorry about that!

Comment: The reason messages *Unknown class HiraganaViewController in Interface Builder file* and *[<UIViewController 0x7fa939d12790> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Question.'* are pretty meaningful: It looks like that you didn't change the type of the affected class to `HiraganaViewController` in IB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the crash log:

> 2020-12-01 12:42:41.206345-0800 final_proj690[3252:142523]
> [Storyboard] Unknown class HiraganaViewController in Interface Builder
> file.
>
> 2020-12-01 12:42:41.224722-0800 final_proj690[3252:142523] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
> reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fa939d12790>
> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
> coding-compliant for the key Question.'

Shows 2 different problems:

### Problem 1:

It says you reference a class `HiraganaViewController` which you don't define.

Yet I see a class definition for that class in the source code you posted. Open the "HiraganaViewController.swift" file in Xcode, and then select the "file inspector". Make sure that there is a checked entry in your "target membership" section that includes that source file into your application.

### Problem 2:

You have an IBOutlet named `Question`. It looks as though that view is not connected to its outlet. That may be caused by the first error. If you fix the first error and this still occurs:

Go into the storyboard and select the `HiraganaViewController` in its scene. Then select the connection inspector, look for an entry for `Question`, and click the X on it to break the link to the IBOutlet. Then open a second assitant editor and control-drag from the Question object to the `IBOutlet` declaration.

Comment: Can you post a comment telling readers of this thread exactly what was wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I had to delete the view and and redo all the IBoutlets and it worked. I think it had something to do with Problem #1 that you posted, I was not careful with my class and ID naming.